# зачем производители компютеров предлагают свои драйвера если в windows 7 уже есть.?

Tags: windows, ос, драйвер

Скажите пожалуйста, 
**зачем** на официальных сайтах производителей компьютеров, в разделе "центр загрузки": если выбрать OS windows 7 - предлагают драйвера на сетевую карту, аудио, wifi, камера и прочие драйвера, которые уже встроенные по дифолту в windows 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Зачастую в win встроены "стандартные" драйвера устройств, подходящие не под конкретную железяку, а под "поколение" железяк. Бывали случаи, что конкретная железка отказывалась работать или работала некорректно. Опять же не стоит забывать, что драйвер под конкретную плату может предоставлять расширенные возможности ее использования, по сравнению со стандартным драйвером.

2) Да, набор драйверов в win7+ большой и зачастую их хватает, однако стоит помнить, что существуют другие ОС: даже на данный момент многие пользуются xp, не надо забывать и про Linux-семейство.

Comment: Что вы порекомендуете, имею win7 и диспечер устройств показывает все исправно и система работает исправно. Устанавливать драйвера отдельно на сетевую карту, звуковую и т.п. ?

Comment: Если Вас все устраивает в работе Вашего ПК, то зачем? :)
Если что-то не устраивает, то конечно в первую очередь стоит обратиться к свежим оригинальным драйверам